# Does anyone know of a 'linked' wheel/scroller type jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, linked-list

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that has the same functionality as 'linked' or 'chained' drop-down select menus, but with a mobile wheel/spinner style interface similar to this plugin:-

[jQuery mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/)

So essentially I would like to be able to select an option on a wheel, and then have the options dynamically generated in the second wheel, dependant upon the first wheel selection.

Does anybody know of anything out there, google hasn't thrown up much and i'd rather not reinvent the wheel in this case unless I have to.

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't adapt mobiscroll to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I suppose you're right,  I was in a hurry and figured there must be something out there already.  It doesn't look that way though.  Ah well.  Thanks anyway!